# Android Facebook API - Query score top 10 users of the app

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, leaderboard

Kindly any idea or the possibility to query the list of the top 10 scores of an application. The users doesnt need to be friends with the current logged user.
Maybe the functionality is not permited through Graph API but i can't find any clear statement about it in the official docs.

Comment: Did you tried anything ? What did you already setup for your app ?

Comment: I set up the leaderboard including the scores of user friends with the Graph API request **/APP_ID/scores** and the right permissions without any issue, also i can query just the user score with **/me/scores**. But i can't find a way to tell _all application scores_.

Comment: There is no way. If you want that feature, you will have to build it on your end.

Comment: Thank you @CBroe for your precious feedback!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way. If you want to have that feature, you will have to build it on your end.